# Jest mocks - how to restore original function between tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have my function:

`report.js`:

```js
const ctrl = {};
const _ = require('lodash');
const boom = require("boom");
const slackNotifications = require('./../../slack/controllers/notifications');
const reportModel = require("./../models/report");

import validationSchema from "./../_validation/report";

ctrl.addReport = async (req, res) => {
  const { body } = req;

  try {
    const validatedData = await validationSchema.validate(body);
    const report = await reportModel(req.dbConnection).addReport(validatedData);

    if (report.reported) {
      await slackNotifications.notify('Notify me!');
      res.status(200).send({ reported: true });
    } else {
      throw boom.serverUnavailable("Can't offer report");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw boom.badRequest(err);
  }
};

module.exports = ctrl;
```

The validation schema is schema created by using yup.js.

Here are the [tests](https://gist.github.com/dszymczuk/7332349c58ff24e519f8824443dd62a7)

The problem is `throw Error when validation failed` test. I've got

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'output' of undefined

from 109 line

`const { output, output: { payload } } = err;`.

But my expected value is error threw by `validationSchema.validate` and caught in 23rd line of my function.

When I run **only this test** everything is ok. I've got the correct error with status code and message.

How can I restore the original function `validationSchema.validate` from this test (84th line)?

I've tried to restore by:

```
jest.mock('./../_validation/report', () => ({
  // validate: jest.fn().mockReset(),
  validate: jest.fn().mockClear(),
}));
```

But I'm not sure that is the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [requireActual](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) in your test to execute the original behaviour for just one test.

This way :

```
jest.mock('./../_validation/report', () => ({
  validate: jest.requireActual('./../_validation/report').validate,
}));
```

This way, the **real** validate will be called
Of course, at the next test (or in a beforeEach), you can re-mock your function.